# How to save/freeze an arbitary pickle model in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using the code from zalando implemented as a progressive GAN by Nvidia. See: https://github.com/zalandoresearch/disentangling_conditional_gans

They use 3 networks while training: `G`, `D` and `Gs`. All three models are an instance of a `Network` class defined in https://github.com/zalandoresearch/disentangling_conditional_gans/blob/master/tfutil.py#L424

These models are stored and loaded using many helper functions which save the 3 models using python's pickle format as `*.pkl`.

I am only interested in exporting the `Gs` model.

How do I convert it into a saved model (as the code doesn't use tf.Saver) and finally a frozen model so that I can easily infer.

Upon loading the models, I do:

```
allvars = [n.name for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node]
Gs_vars = [i for i in allvars if i.split('/')[0] == 'Gs']
```

However, when running this:

```
Gs_saver = tf.train.Saver({"Gs": Gs_vars})
```

it throws an error saying:

```
*** ValueError: Slices must all be Variables: Gs/latents_in
```

The correct implementation of using the `Gs` model is:

```
images = Gs.run(latents, labels, masks, minibatch_size=minibatch_size, num_gpus=config.num_gpus, out_mul=127.5, out_add=127.5, out_shrink=image_shrink, out_dtype=np.uint8)
```

`Gs` requires 3 inputs which are stored as `Gs/latents_in`, `Gs/masks_in` and `Gs/labels_in`.